# PHP session from HTML/Javascript onclick not containing the correct value

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have a PHP pagination menu. Each item form the pagination menu contains an a item.
Pagination script:

```
if ($page_count >= 1 && $page <= $page_count) {
    ?><li class="page-item <? if($page == 1){echo "active";} ?>"><? echo '<a onclick="myScript(1)" class="page-link">1</a></li>';
    $i = max(2, $page - 2);
    if ($i > 2)
    {
        echo ' ... ';
    }
    for (; $i < min($page + 2, $page_count); $i++) {
        ?><li class="page-item <? if($i == $page){echo "active";} ?>"><? echo '<a onclick="myScript('. $i .')" class="page-link">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }
    if ($i != $page_count)
    {
        echo ' ... ';
    }
    ?><li class="page-item <? if($page_count == $page){echo "active";} ?>"><? echo '<a onclick="myScript('. $page_count .')" class="page-link">' . $page_count . '</a></li>';                   
    }
```

When a user clicks on a list `<a>` item, I want to get the value of the selected item and create a PHP session, containing this item.
This is the Javascript that should create the session:

```
function myScript(clicked_id) 
{       
    <? $_SESSION["page"] = "clicked_id"; ?>
    alert(<? echo "$_SESSION[page]"; ?>);
}
```

This is working, and in the Javascript alert I get the correct value of the selected item, for example " 2 "  if I clicked the list item where the $i value is "2".

The page should refresh, and then, when I check the page session value, I would expect the value " 2 ". However, this is not the case. The value is actually "clicked_id".

This is the code where I check the session:

```
$page = 1;                                          
if(!empty($_SESSION["page"])) {
    $page = $_SESSION["page"];      
    if($page == 'clicked_id')
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
}
```

My question is: why is the session not containing the correct value? In the alert the value is correct, but in my check the session doesn't contain the correct value any more. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It's really basic, You initialize your  $_SESSION["page"] with "clicked_id" string and you show it just the line after with an alert. What you expecting ? It's like doing this in javascript: var potato = 33; alert(potato); Of course you will have 33 in your alert box.

Comment: @Hexxefir, but why would the var first be 33 in the session in the alert, but later be "clicked_id" when reading the session then?

Comment: You trying to use bunch of things in a single php file. Session is a super global variable for keeping seesion alive in php and i don't understand why you use it for pagination. Use Ajax to do this, this is the right way. But i see your coding lvl is really low. Making a php file with HTM, javascript and php code is a bad paractice in most cases. So for short answer: You have a javascript function call myScript. In that function you put "clicked_id" as value. and the line after you send a alert with this value. Javascript will not execute a php function like this.

Comment: PHP work with request -> response, you using session cause you trying to find a way to keep alive a value. Everything in your code are bad. Learn first javascript and Ajax, after PHP and in couples of months you will understand what you doing, cause now you trying learn what i learn in a university in few minutes. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and JS are not compatible; you may not simply include a PHP function in JS. 
PHP gets evaluated server-side and javascript gets evaluated client side.

What you probably want to do is to replace your navigations items by links to redirect the user to the desired page.

To understand how PHP works and the result generated by the server, right click on your page and then "View the source code of the page".

Comment: thank you for the information. How would I go about it without using using direct URL's. I wanna set sessions on click on A elements.

Comment: you shoul use ajax or cookie